# How to remove chat history from quickblox dialog iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, quickblox

### Quickblox iOS Remove Chat History

I have integrated Quickblox iOS (Objective-C) SDK in my app for chat module.

Now, I want to clear all chat history done under the one dialog,

Below is the code to remove specific chat message from dialog. But It's not removing all the chat history.

---

```
NSSet *mesagesIDs = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"560a7e8ba0eb472a6300004d", @"560a7e9ea28f9a0cda003018", nil];

[QBRequest deleteMessagesWithIDs:mesagesIDs forAllUsers:NO successBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

}];
```

---

Kindly help me if anyone having any working solution for my request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dialog ID from QBChatDialog that you want to delete.

Objective-C version

```
- (void)deleteDialogWithID:(NSString *)dialogID {
   __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
   // Deleting dialog from Quickblox and cache.
   [ServicesManager.instance.chatService deleteDialogWithID:dialogID completion:^(QBResponse *response) {
       if (response.success) {
          __typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
          [strongSelf.tableView reloadData];
          [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
       } else {
          [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Can not delete dialog"];
          NSLog(@"can not delete dialog: %@", response.error);
       }
   }];
}
```

Swift version

```
// Deletes dialog from server and cache.
ServicesManager.instance().chatService.deleteDialog(withID: dialog.id!, completion: { (response) -> Void in
    guard response.isSuccess else {
      SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "SA_STR_ERROR_DELETING".localized)
      print(response.error?.error)
      return
    }
  SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "SA_STR_DELETED".localized)
})
```